# What does 653 mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, altered-carbon

Throughout  *Altered Carbon* 653 is mentioned quite a few times, but I never quite grasped what it was.  What is 653?

Comment: It’s the id of the law that allows to revive people for testimony even if their religion says no (linked to a lot of things in the show: protests, etc).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Resolution 653*** is a proposal to change the existing law to allow murder victims to be “spun up” / resleeved so they can testify against their killers - even if they have Neo-C coding.

Neo-C coding means that they are Neo-Catholics and have a religious objection to being "brought back from the dead" regardless of the reason since they believe that a person should only die once.

**Why is it important?**

> Resolution 653 is significant in the series because Reileen (Dichen Lachman) takes advantage of the Neo-C clause to get away with murder.
>
> The sister of Takeshi (Joel Kinnaman and Will Yun Lee) is the rich and powerful owner of an elite brothel called Head in the Clouds, where the patrons can kill the sex workers if they want to.
>
> Reileen illegally changes her workers’ codes to Neo-C so they cannot be spun up to after they are murdered in her.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://www.express.co.uk/showbiz/tv-radio/919614/altered-carbon-what-is-resolution-653-explained-neo-c-netflix-takeshi-kovacs)</sup>